# Race condition firing events in AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, events, race-condition

I have some troubles firing and removing events in the right chronicle order. The code below gives the following output:

- save poster into db, and dispatch event
- calling service, dispatch event removed = false
- calling service, dispatch event removed = false
- calling service, dispatch event removed = true
- save poster into db, and dispatch event
- save poster into db, and dispatch event

of course this should be more something like:

- save poster into db, and dispatch event
- calling service, dispatch event removed = true
- save poster into db, and dispatch event
- calling service, dispatch event removed = true
- save poster into db, and dispatch event
- calling service, dispatch event removed = true

Can someone help me with this? I'm running out of ideas on how to tackle this.

thx!

```
    for(var i:int = 0;i< 3;i++){
        createPoster();         
    }

    function createPoster(){
        Main.db.savePoster();
        Main.db.addEventListener(Config.evt_SAVEPOSTER_READY, callService);
    }

    function callService(){
       Main.db.removeEventListener(Config.evt_SAVEPOSTER_READY, callService);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are registering same function `callService` for same event `Config.evt_SAVEPOSTER_READY` on single `EvenDispatcher` object`db`. So as soon first savePoster dispatches the event after successfully saving the poster, db receives the event and three eventHandlers (in this case callService) are called because callService is registered thrice. So one solution would be dispatching the events from Poster.

```
for(var i:int = 0;i< 3;i++){
  createPoster();
}
function createPoster(){
  poster = Main.db.savePoster();
  poster.addEventListener(Config.evt_SAVEPOSTER_READY, callService);
}
function callService(e:PosterEvent){
  e.target.removeEventListener(Config.evt_SAVEPOSTER_READY, callService);
}
```

Comment: hmmm good point. I'll implement it and come back to it. Thx for useful reply!

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked what happens when you loop through one item only? Seems to me you are not queuing your routines properly.

You might probably want to add an event listener to your Main.db object only once and remove it when you have gotten all your 'posters' successfully saved.

Comment: Hey Thx for the reply. Yes i did, there is no problem when looping once. 

I have put a timer in the for-loop and if i trigger the createPoster every 1000 milliseconds then there is no problem. Seems like the for-loop is going to fast for the event being able to be removed.

Comment: Adding a delay to solve the issue is a weak strategy. I might post some sample code later to explain my point above.

Answer (score 0):

Is the db call (`Main.db.savePoster();`) synchronous - does it return only after the action is completed? Since you are calling `addEventListener` after the db call, the event listener (for the first iteration at least) will not be called if the db-call is synchronous.

Is the `Main.db` the same instance in all the three iterations? If it is, you don't have to register the same event listener thrice for it - once would be enough. Call `addEventListener` before starting the for-loop. Keep a counter for tracking the number of calls to the callService and call `removeEventListener` once the counter hits loop count (3, in this case).